# HCl Concentration vs HDPE Permeation

Tags: aqueous-solution, gas-laws, polymers

I've learned that HCl escapes HDPE. I looked up why and it turns out it's because of the small size of the molecule. That factor is unlikely to be affected by the concentration of HCl in water, but I was thinking: does water exert an "attractive" effect on HCl such that HCl would escape an HDPE container from a solution of 30% HCl (for example) over an order of magnitude more than from a 20% solution?

Does this phenomenon take place? What order of difference in HCl permeating an HDPE vessel could I expect between solutions of 10%, 20%, 30% concentration? (just to have a general idea of how big the phenomenon is, if at all)

Comment: Check Fick's first law on diffusion : $J \propto - dc/dx$.

Comment: So the relationship is exponential (squared)?

Comment: ? I don't think so.